# Remove extra folders from Mercurial repository

Tags: android, mercurial, tortoisehg

I have an Android Gradle project that is recently converted from ant project resulting to have a lot of unversioned extra directories in Mercurial repository.

Is there any easy way to remove all "unversioned" directories that does not contain any "versioned" files?

I have tried [hg purge](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PurgeExtension) command with many flags. But for example hg purge with --dirs flag does not remove directories that contains something (for example contains an empty directory).

Of course I can re-clone the whole project but this must be done on our [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)-slave servers too and that's why single command could be a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purge command worked finally.

`hg purge --all`